# Sum collection into groups

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have data that represents demographics by age with regions. Querying for this data is working it seems, now where I am struggling is the idea of creating summations by within regions. Laravel is a new framework for so perhaps this has been answered elsewhere, please direct me where if this is the case.

```
// my data is Region and Person's age
Region 1 - 28
Region 5 - 14
Region 8 - 73
Region 3 - 55
Region 3 - 45
...
```

And so on. This is example but I have many thousands of records. How can I get a grouping like

```
['Region 1' => ['1-10' => 434, '11-20' => 543, '21-30' => 234, ...],
['Region 2' => ['1-10' => 443, '11-20' => 123, '21-30' => 939, ...],
['Region 3' => ['1-10' => 484, '11-20' => 987, '21-30' => 424, ...]
....
```

I began with `$results->groupBy('region')` but I do not know how to get to next level grouping ages. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Your question is still ambiguous. Can you provide more context?

Comment: Yes apologies. Within regions I need to sum age ranges like 1 years old to 10 years old, 11 years old to 20 years old, and more like so. Each region is a separate upper level group